# Cannot dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 LTS along with Windows 8.1

Tags: boot

Got a brand new Lenovo G 510 laptop with the following specs:-
aled
i5-4200m , 8 GB RAM ,1 TB HDD, 2 GB AMD-RADEON GRAPHICS CARD with Windows 8.1.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04, alloting  around 150 GB, inclusive of 8 gb for swap and  10 gb  for bios space( where bootloader location was set) , but I am not able to dual boot alongside Windows 8.1. I installed Ubuntu in Legacy Mode coz I couldn't boot from USB in UEFI MODE. Ubuntu is installed, but it wouldn't load. It goes directly to WIndows 8.1. I also updated grub, but wouldn't work. Please help me to sort this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be careful, I somehow lost windows 8 and have no idea where it went.

Comment: 10 gb for the bios_grub partition?  It only needs to be 1 mb ( actually 64k is fine ).  Also if your system is booting in efi mode, then you have to install in efi mode.

Answer (score 0):

Actaully I was too facing this problem. I suggest you to do a boot repair. Make a bootable Ubuntu pendrive and den boot it through that and then after booting to ubunty click on try ubuntu and den follow the steps listed : http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot

Answer (score 0):

What i recommend is for a new WUBI version that Canonical is releasing.
As of 2012 computers with UEFI installed has put a gate around the hope of installing UBUNTU.
There is a page around Ubuntu's Documentations that gives u a rough explanation of installing it alongside.
There is also another way of doing that but it will require u to obtain a windows cd
Good Luck! :)
(if u want the last method, hit me up)
(14 Year old here lols :) )

Comment: But Wubi wouldn't work on Windows 8 (or higher version of Windows) pre-installed systems.

Comment: wubi is nolonger a recommended method of installation, in fact, I believe it is recommended against.

Answer (score 0):

You can install grub to a blank USB so that the USB will load grub just like it would an installation or live session. To do this, boot into a live session using an installation **DVD** with a blank USB drive plugged into your computer as well. Open a terminal or press CTRL + ALT + F2 to sign into a text session and execute the following commands.

First, locate your Ubuntu partition device number:

```
sudo lsblk
```

My Ubuntu partition is at **/dev/sda3** and I will be using this as an example for the following commands, however, your's may be /dev/sda2 or even /dev/sda5. Use the output of **lsblk** to determine what you should substitute.

You will also need to know the drive letters for the USB. I will use **/dev/sdb** as an example, however, again your's may be something else.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sdb
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /
sudo chroot /
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Leave the USB in when you want to boot into Ubuntu and the Grub menu will start from there.

As usual, make sure the USB drive is formatted to fat32.

This method bypasses the normal boot sequence if USB is set to boot before the hard drive in the bios settings.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually could boot Ubuntu, after chosing the option  "Install along with Windows 8"  while installation, it automatically got installed to an ext4 partition, with additional 8 GB swap. But the problem is, I have to disable UEFI and use Legacy to boot into Ubuntu( But in Legacy, WIndows 8.1 wouldn't work) and then to get back to Windows 8.1, I have to go back BIOS menu and change to UEFI again. Everything is working fine in Ubuntu, except for Wi-fi :/. Dono what the issue with that is.

Comment: With your partition scheme, grub is installed to the Ubuntu partition instead of the MBR. If a USB is set to boot before the hard drive, the USB can basically function the same way an MBR would have if you were using an older version of windows.